# Is there a way to translate Sanity Studio?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sanity

I'm trying to use Sanity for the first times, as it looked a good headless CMS approach.

But I didn't find any ways to change the interface language. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to translate the Studio interface, unfortunately :/ But it's a popular feature request, so maybe sometime in the future!